# How to read this DNA inversion diagram?

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, mutations

In the following diagram about chromosome inversion, I don't understand:

1. Why do we need to take the reverse complement from step 1 to 2? Isn't inversion just reversing the bases in the region?
2. How is the bottom diagram derived? For example, where does the `ACCCCACTC` come from? I thought it should be: `GACTGCCGT` for 5'→3' and `CTGACGGCA` for 3'→5' (inversion of the sequences in the second step).

[image]

http://web2.mendelu.cz/af_291_projekty2/vseo/print.php?page=315&typ=html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your misunderstanding probably stems from the differences of definition of inverse in bioinformatics (reverse) and cell biology/genetics.

What is shown in the picture is chromosomal inversion, in which the segment of DNA gets cut, flipped and ligated. Note that in the DNA, `5'` would be ligated to `3'` and vice-versa. So the `5'` of the bottom strand i.e. `T` is ligated to the `3'` of the top strand i.e. `C`. Similarly for the other ends. Therefore, you see a reverse complementation.

The sequence of the top strand however should have been `5'-TTAC-TGCCGTCAG-TAG-3'` which has been incorrectly shown as `5'-TTAC-TGGGGTGAG-TAG-3'`. That is a mistake in the picture.

Have a look at this picture <sup>[1]</sup>:

[image]

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>Okamura, Kohji, John Wei, and Stephen W. Scherer. "[Evolutionary implications of inversions that have caused intra-strand parity in DNA](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1471-2164-8-160)." *BMC Genomics* 8.1 (2007): 160.</sub>

Comment: That’s what I thought as well at first but if you actually look at the sequence of the red (flipped) bit, you’ll notice that it differs between the middle and the bottom picture: the red bit reads 5′→3′ TGCCGTCAG in the middle picture, but TGGGGTGAG in the bottom picture.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh! That seems like a mistake in the picture.